# Passing a struct item as the parameter

Tags: c

I understand it is possible to pass a struct as an argument etc.

But is it possible to have the parameter preset so only a specific struct item can be passed such:

```
struct inventory* searchForItem(struct stockItem.componentType code){
```

I'm getting : error: expected ';' , ', ' before token

EDIT:

```
typedef struct stockItem {
    char *componentType;
    char *stockCode;
    int numOfItems;
    int price;
} stockItem;
```

Comment: ``item` or type? C only or C++?

Comment: What is `componentType`? Where and how is it defined?

Comment: Just C. componentType is char in a struct

Comment: I'll ad the code for the struct

Comment: Then pass char* or directly the struct or make a new (opaque?)  type (!!!) for it.

Comment: I had char* originally, doesn't seem very safe to me. What do you mean opaque? @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: Just use special `typedef` both in struct definition and in function declaration. It will make code more readable. `doesn't seem very safe to me` - yes, C isn't so safe.

Comment: I am interested in "why" you want this as passing `char *` or `stockItem *` seem so readily an alternative.  By knowing the reason,  perhaps the higher level problem can be solved.

Comment: the problem was solved @chux

Comment: @session_start The post was solved for you, yet SO is also a body of knowledges used by at least 10s of thousands.  By adding more detail to your needs, this post becomes more valuable for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since the comments on the other answer are too constrained)

First you define a new type for `componentType`, like this:

```
typedef char *stockItem_componentType; // Naming subject to conventions
```

Now in your structure, you use this type instead of simple `char*`. This is optional, but very much recommended. Like this:

```
typedef struct stockItem {
    stockItem_componentType componentType;
    char *stockCode;
    int numOfItems;
    int price;
} stockItem;
```

And finally, your function prototype is:

```
struct inventory* searchForItem(stockItem_componentType code);
```

Comment: Thank you, is this considered a better alternative than just passing the char *? also where do I write typedef char *stockItem_componentType; do I put it just above the struct ?

Comment: @session_start You would put it above the struct. Personally, I think using `char*` directly is better in C since it is immediately obvious what it is. The main benefit of this is if the type can change so you can only change it on one place (e.g. if you originally had `uint8_t` as some code, but wanted to expand it to `uint32_t`, you only need to change that one line). Mostly though.. Stick to the style of the project you're working on.. Or if you're starting a new one, pick a style and stick to it.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep as is. Thank you for clearing it up for me

Answer (score 2):

The type of that component is `char *`, so just make that the type of the parameter.

```
struct inventory* searchForItem(char *code){
```

If you want to make the type more strict, make a typedef for the field in question:

```
typedef char * stockItem_componentType;

typedef struct stockItem {
    stockItem_componentType componentType;
    char *stockCode;
    int numOfItems;
    int price;
} stockItem;

struct inventory* searchForItem(stockItem_componentType code){
```

Note that this hides a pointer behind a `typedef` which is not recommended.  Then people reading your code (including yourself) won't know just by looking at it that it's a pointer, which can lead to confusion.

Comment: The answer is no then, I had that originally

Comment: @session_start `typedef char *stockItem_componentType`, then have the type as `stockItem_componentType`.